# How to loop a variable into a sql call

Tags: php

I want to get all `teacher_id` from the database and then loop each of the `teacher_id` in another sql.

I get the `teacher_id` like this:

```
$teachersql = "SELECT DISTINCT teacher_name, teacher_id FROM `dancers` WHERE school = '$ownerSchool'";
        $teacherres = mysqli_query($con,$teachersql);

        while($chartData2=mysqli_fetch_array($teacherres)){
             $teacher_Id = $chartData2['teacher_id'];


            }
        ?>
```

I get an array of the `ID`. Now I want to use that array and then do another sql using each of the `ID` so that I can do a count of how many beginners are there for each teacher.

What I am getting is

```
Teacher     |   Level
Liv         |   Beginner
Liv         |   Beginner
Liv         |   Novice
Tee         |   Open champ
Mike        |   Major
Liv         |   Beginner
```

But what I want is to make a sql call for each teacher and then count the number of beginners for that teacher.

So if I do `$teachersql2 = "SELECT * FROM`dancers`WHERE teacher_id = '$teacher_Id'";`

I want it to make the call for each teacher id in the `$teacher_id array`.
and am looking for this result:

```
Teacher     |   Count
Liv         |   3 Beginner, 1 Novice
Tee         |   1 Open champ
Mike        |   1 Major
```

This way I can put the count (3) into a variable and (1) into a variable to use else where.

full code:

```
// GET TEACHERS


        $teachersql = "SELECT DISTINCT teacher_name, teacher_id FROM `dancers` WHERE school = '$ownerSchool'";
        $teacherres = mysqli_query($con,$teachersql);

        while($chartData2=mysqli_fetch_array($teacherres)){
             $teacher_Id = $chartData2['teacher_id'];
             $teacherNames = $chartData2['teacher_name'];
             $teacherNames = str_replace(' ', '', $teacherNames);
             $teacherNames = str_replace('.', '', $teacherNames);
             $var2 = 'data';
             $newVar2 = $var2 . $teacher_Id . $teacherNames;

            $teachersql2 = "SELECT * FROM `dancers` WHERE teacher_id = '$teacher_Id'";
            $teacherres2 = mysqli_query($con,$teachersql2);
            while($chartData3=mysqli_fetch_array($teacherres2)){
                $preB_percent = $chartData3['current_lvl'];
        ?>
        //CHART BY TEACHERS
        var <?php echo $newVar2; ?> = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['<? $total_students; ?> Pre-Beginners', '<?php $lvl_beginner; ?> Beginners', '<?php $lvl_advanced; ?> Advanced Beginners', '<?php echo $lvl_novice; ?> Novices', '<?php echo $lvl_prizeWinner; ?> Prize Winners', '<?php $lvl_prelim; ?> Prelim Champions', '<?php echo $lvl_open; ?> Open Champions', '<?php echo $lvl_major; ?> Majors'],
            ['<?php echo $preB_percent; ?>', '<?php echo $beginner_percent; ?>', '<?php echo $advanced_percent; ?>', '<?php echo $novice_percent; ?>', '<?php echo $prizeWinner_percent; ?>', '<?php echo $prelim_percent; ?>', '<?php echo $open_percent; ?>', '<?php echo $major_percent; ?>']
        ]);

        <?php }} ?>
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this. But I really need help, i've been stuck for days. I hope my question makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your two queries into one using `group by` like the SQL bellow:

```
SELECT teacher_name, current_lvl, count(teacher_id) as count
FROM dancers
WHERE school = '$ownerSchool'  
GROUP BY current_lvl, teacher_id
ORDER BY teacher_name ASC
```

The result produced will be similar to this schema:

```
Teacher     |  Level        | Count
Liv         |  Beginner     |   3
Liv         |  Novice       |   1
Tee         |  Open champ   |   1
Mike        |  major        |   1
```

And you can merge your results using the php code to generate your data chart

```
$results = mysqli_query($con, $teacher_sql);

$last_teacher_name = "";
$current_index;
$chart_data = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

    $teacher_name = $row["teacher_name"];
    $current_lvl = $row["current_lvl"];
    $total_dancers = $row["count"];

    if ($teacher_name != $last_teacher_name ) {
        $chart_data += ["teacher_name" => $teacher_name];
        $last_teacher_name = $teacher_name;
        $current_index = count($chart_data) - 1;
    }

    $chart_data[$current_index]["current_lvl"] = $current_lvl;
    $chart_data[$current_index]["count"] = $total_dancers;
}
```

**Note:**
It is important to pay attention to the sql injection as punctuated by @Dharman

Use [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) To prevent this problem use